# how can i use youtube chromeless player in desktop application?

Tags: c++, qt, desktop, youtube-api

i like to use youtube chromeless player in my QT c++ application
im using qwebkit , but in the youtube doc's its says:   "
To test any of these calls, you must have your file running on a webserver...."
how can i overcome this restriction and use chromeless player or some alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly do you want from Youtube Chrome-less player. If it is the outlook and GUI then you can create exactly like this in QT. If it is the playability of the files you can use several open source media file APIs, or even QT Media extensions. Youtube chromeless player is just an swf application that can host a file which it can fetch from web. You can also try by giving the local file name as translated to its local host string e.g: using http://localhost/.... Or using file:///C/files/....